# Pygame rect.inflate function does not seem to work

Tags: python, pygame

How does Pygame's "rect.inflate_ip"  function work? 
In this code, I am trying to inflate this rectangle by some value `zoom`:

```
rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen,block.color,(block.x+scx,block.y+scy,10,10))
rect.inflate_ip(zoom,zoom)
```

But this does not have any effect. Why?

Comment: print `rect ` before and after `inflate_ip` and you'll see the difference. Of course, it doesn't affect the rectangle drawn on the screen. `pygame.draw.rect` does not generate an object. This function fills a rectangular area on the screen and returns that area.

Comment: @Rabbid76  Oh, that's interesting. Why does it not seem to have any render change?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ohhh. I see. I might seem dumb here, but I'm kinda new to pygame...  how would I make it affect the rendering?

Comment: Read my answer down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print `rect` before and after `inflate_ip` and you'll see the difference. Of course, it doesn't affect the rectangle drawn on the screen. [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) does not generate an object. This function fills a rectangular area on the screen and returns that area. You have to create a [`pagame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object and use that for drawing. e.g.:

```py
rect = pygame.Rect(block.x+scx, block.y+scy, 10, 10)
rect.inflate_ip(zoom, zoom) 
pygame.draw.rect(screen, block.color, rect)
```